# How can I create OpenSSL output that compares to OpenSSL C++ output to generate unit tests?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, encryption, terminal, openssl

I'm using a C++ wrapper for OpenSSL's AES-256-CBC encryption that follows the recipe from [OpenSSL docs](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption). It's meant to take some data to encrypt, a key and an initialization vector, and return encrypted bytes.

Now on the relative sense, encryption and decryption works fine. I can encrypt anything and decrypt it and retrieve the original data. However, I'd like to test it *in the absolute sense*. So, I'm using OpenSSL in command line/terminal to create encrypted data, and then inject it in my tests. But the outputs are not matching, and I'm not sure where to start or how to systematically tackle this.

To produce the hex data:

```
printf '%s' 'Hello world!' | xxd -ps
```

which returns `48656c6c6f20776f726c6421`.

Then, to encrypt it with OpenSSL:

```
printf '%s' '48656c6c6f20776f726c6421' | xxd -r -ps | openssl aes-256-cbc -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000 -k 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 -nosalt | xxd -ps
```

which gives `f1b486ded0fd22dad9dbdab2205f61c2`.

`xxd -r` converts hex to bytes, and `xxd` does the opposite. I tried also with plain `Hello world!` without `xxd` in the beginning, but also is wrong. The result always doesn't match what I get in the C++ OpenSSL code. What am I missing here?

Find a [minimal, verifiable, complete example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7648d8897d0771c3) of my code that demonstrates the result.

Comment: Could you post the results you are getting?

Comment: Even with the same IV, padding bytes should be random, so the encrypted data will be different.

Comment: @prmottajr Done.

Comment: @RichardCritten The result is 100% deterministic. The only nondeterministic thing was the salt, which I removed. Repeating doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was that I'm using the wrong command line parameter. It should be `-K` for the key, not `-k`. This is the correct format:

```
printf '%s' '48656c6c6f20776f726c6421' | xxd -r -ps | openssl aes-256-cbc -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000 -K 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 -nosalt | xxd -ps
```

and this gives the exact same result as OpenSSL in C++.